Do hypotheses need a “how” explanation or are predictions enough to validate them?
I will try to illustrate this question with an example.
Suppose there is a person who claims to bend a spoon with his mind, and crucially, claims that somehow, someway, purely his immaterial thoughts physically affect and bend the spoon.
There is then a lab test and we simply ask the person to bend a spoon. Let’s assume that this is repetitively done in a controlled environment where we can try our best to rule out any forms of cheating. Let’s also assume that without fail, the spoons bend.
Presumably, despite the successful predictions, we will not have a “how” explanation here, as we usually do in the case of physical explanations. There would be no known way of understanding how, exactly, something immaterial creates a physical effect (if that is even coherent). And technically, it is still possible that some form of cheating is occurring. If cheating is occurring, this would imply that some known or unknown physical process (that doesn’t involve mind control) is occurring which is cleverly hidden by the person we’re testing.
Per the Duhem-Quine thesis, the predictions would still match this hypothesis. But if we assume tons and tons of successful predictions, can we finally believe or increase our credence in this pure mind control process, or should we still fall back into thinking there is a hidden physical explanation given the absence of a “how”?

You have used the term " immaterial " several times in the past... would you mind clarifying whether or not you define RF energy as material or immaterial?

Why is this formulated as if there couldn't be hypotheses of both kinds and as if they exist in a vacuum? Some (phenomenological) only describe what is observed, others propose 'mechanisms' behind it. "How" usually refers to relating outward phenomena to more fundamental theories already in existence, i.e., ultimately, to other classes of phenomena. And that will be pursued after laws of 'spoon-bending' as such are established, as happened with magnetism. It was action at a distance before it became a field and got bundled with electricity. 'Mind control' is just irrelevant at early stages.

@Conifold It’s not formulated as if there couldn’t be hypotheses of both kinds. If there are successful predictions and a mechanism/posits/etc to explain how it is all happening, you have both. The question is what happens if one is missing. What should we believe with respect to the mind control hypothesis if we end up finding no mechanism for it (I.e. no field/etc equivalent like in magnetism)?

You treating "controlled by mind" and "physical process" as being mutually exclusive presupposes dualism.

"credence in this pure mind control process, or should we still fall back into thinking there is a hidden physical explanation" - what would be the difference? Supposing I believe (due to experimental demonstration) that every time you think about bending a spoon, the spoon bends. Then what's the difference between me concluding that some "pure mind control" process exists, that none of my physical experimental conditions can directly detect, and me concluding that some "hidden physical explanation" exists, that none of my physical experimental conditions can detect?

One common approach is to refuse to distinguish between competing theories that make the same testable predictions. Especially when, as in this case, both theories just say "X happens because [something that explains literally nothing other than X]". When (if ever) will the "pure mind" hypothesis and the "hidden physical explanation" hypothesis make different testable predictions? The answer to that might help decide what to do while waiting for the happy day when we can experimentally disprove at least one of them.

Many successful theories have no "how". Here are two examples:
When Newton formulated his Law of Gravitation, he postulated a force that decreases by an inverse square law, because this fit the observations and successfully predicted future observations. But he couldn't explain how this force worked. It wouldn't be until Einstein came up with the Theory of General Relativity that we had an explanation in terms of warping of space-time.
When Darwin came up with evolution by natural selection, he also didn't know how traits were passed on to progeny, or how the traits changed. The first ideas of this process came when Mendel performed his tests of genetics, but he still didn't know the underlying process. We didn't have a real explanation until DNA was discovered and we saw how cells passed on genetic material as they divided, and how this was recombined during sexual reproduction.
Furthermore, even when we have explanations like these, they just raise new questions about more fundamental causes. How mass warps spacetime wasn't really explained until we discovered the Higgs Field, and we don't yet know what causes that. Similarly, there are many details in the way DNA and RNA work that have yet to be worked out; we also don't know how all this got started (abiogenesis). It's quite possible that we can never now the complete answer to how anything happens, we just keep producing more detailed models. There may be an infinite regress of explanations.

how mass causes space-time to warp is explained by the higgs boson field.  Now we just need to answer why the higgs boson field creates drag on mass, and when we answer that we need to explain why that thing happens...

Exactly. I've added a discussion of the possibly infinite regress of explanations.

@Nosajimiki Only if one subscribes to the Principle of Sufficient Reason. At a certain point, maybe we should just say... "Meh, it just is." ; )

@JD Indeed, these always remind me of the series of questions that a child might ask when they start with "Why is the sky blue?" Eventually Mom or Dad has to put a stop to it with "Let's get ice cream"

@JD For sanity's sake, yes you should.  But scientifically speaking, even when we finally distil everything down to a single unified theory of everything, the question will remain: "Why does our universe follow any of these rules?" Even though we've run every experiment we can run and proven without a doubt that all things act in XYZ way, an endless chain of whys always ends in an unanswerable question, circle reasoning, or some variation of "God did it".

If only I could use mind control to vote twice for this answer!

But these theories explain how something happens, they just create new "how" questions. It's like moving a frontier of knowledge. Whereas the situation in the post does not seem to move the frontier of knowledge.

@rus9384 Do they? Newton just provided a formula that describes the behavior, but doesn't explain why or how masses behave that way.

@rus9384 But I can see what you mean. "Natural selection" and "survival of the fittest" are "how", but they leave open the question of how traits are passed on and change (answered by molecular genetics).

The essence of a theory is to suggest a 'how' (a causal system). Think about the theory of gravity: what we observe is that objects released in the air fall towards the earth in a consistent and measurable way. We then make a theory that there is some underlying force — the force of gravity — that causes these observations to occur. Do we see 'gravity'? No. Do we know what 'gravity' is? Not really. All we have is a whole bunch of observations of things falling, and a nice math-ridden story that seems to explain why we see that happen.
So let's take your example. What we observe is spoons bending in a consistent and measurable way. Now we build theories about why that happens. One person builds a theory that the observed effects are due to some purely mental process; another person theorizes it's magnetism; a third theorizes that this is a specific property of spoons; others theorize other things. There's obviously a cause, because we can see the effect; there's obviously something the spoon-bender is doing, because the spoons bend when he says they will bend. At this point two scientific activities occur:

Testing theories to exclude those that don't fit with measurable data.
Rationalizing theories with respect to other related and tested theories

The first is what we generally think of as science proper.  For instance, we might set up magnetometers around a spoon to see if there is any unusual magnetic activity while the spoon is bending. We can use that to exclude, support, or refine the 'magnetism' theory. Or we might try bending a fork or a knife, which could exclude, support, or refine the 'it's a spoon-thing' theory. Not much controversial here…
The second is more on the philosophical side of science. It rests on the idea that anomalies are undesirable and theories should be generalizable. Scientists might resist the idea that the spoons are being bent by pure mental will because the effects of pure mental will don't (yet) appear anywhere else in the literature. If someone could bend spoons with their mind, we would expect that other things could be done with the mind as well, so that we would observe a general class of effects akin to 'The Force' from Star Wars. We don't see that, but… maybe we will if we look for it. That's the tension: science is going to resist accepting something that seems anomalous, but ought to look to make sure it's actually anomalous, and not just hidden.

Don't forget the other theory, that you are being presented with false evidence. Which has been pretty conclusively demonstrated to be the case for this particular trick.

@keshlam: well, to be perfectly accurate, there's no such thing as 'false evidence'. Observations are observations, they're neither true nor false. There are theories that interpret evidence in false or misleading ways, and there are manipulations of our perceptual systems that make us think we've perceived one thing when another thing happened, but neither of those is 'false'. liars mess with our minds, not with our senses.

Liars convince us that we are observing something other than that which is happening. I'd settle for inaccurate or misleading if you object to false.

@keshlam: My objection to 'false' is that we observe what we observe. I mean, we see the sun rise in the morning. We know that isn't what's really happening (the world is turning, yah?), but that's what we see. seeing the sun rise isn't 'false', 'rising' is just a wrong interpretation of the observation. If we see spoons bend, that isn't 'false' because it's what we see. Maybe the explanation of that involves trickery, but that doesn't make what we see 'false', it just interprets it differently. We don't judge evidence; we judge theories.

If we see spoons bend because a bent spoon replaced straight spoon... Sorry, I'm a scientist rather than a philosopher, I have no problem with the idea that data can be contaminated

@keshlam: The minute you say 'because' you are invoking causation and developing a theory. And of course we can test your theory about replaced spoons and see if it's supported. But we cannot assume your theory is true a priori; that's anti-scientific. What we see is spoons bending; we develop theories to explain wha causes that.

Language is slippery. We see a bent spoon, and someone tells us we've seen a spoon bend. That person is already selling us assumptions about causation. Too many of the arguments I see presented here want to set off certain statements as beyond disputation.

@JonathanZ: Everybody has their theories; that's why it's so important to separate observation  from theory. When we start by seeing without interpretation, then we can start to measure interpretations. Language is slippery, yes, but the worst mistake we can make is to let language dictate observation, not the other way around.

It would be great if we could start by seeing without interpretation. Unfortunately, that's not how the brain usually works.

If someone claims that they have a "theory" that explains how the roulette table works, and proceed to predict a sequence of black, red, and greens with 99.9% accuracy over one million trials, most scientific thinkers, barring dishonesty as an explanation, would accept the predictive success as a strong validation of the theory without any other explanatory aspect. Such an approach is actually a type of explanation known as statistical explanation (SEP). This is part of a larger collection of possible forms of mathematical explanation that occur in the sciences (SEP). From the first SEP article:

Thus if it is a statistical law that the probability of recovery from streptococcus, given that one has taken penicillin, is high, and Jones has taken penicillin and recovered, this information can be used to provide an IS explanation of Jones’s recovery. However if the probability of recovery is low (e.g., less than 0.5), given that Jones has taken penicillin, then, even if Jones recovers, we cannot use this information to provide an IS explanation of his recovery.

In this case, predictably functions as an explanatory law as a type of statistical law. Statistical laws are many; for instance, Zipf's law in linguistics and NLP is a reliable explanation for properties of corpora.
But of course, there are other forms of explanatory laws, and another popular approach are causal explanations in science (SEP) which are intuitively very satisfying. Here, causes function as a form of explanation also. Why is it raining in the Amazon today? One could rely on a statistical explanation regarding precipitation in a rain forest, or one could given an explanation in terms of water, gasses, temperatures, cold and warm fronts, etc. Types of causal explanations even go back to Aristotelian categories known as the four causes so one might find a biologist describe Amazonian rainfall as teleological and therefore in the language of final causes.

No, saying How or Why in your Hypothesis turns it into 2 Hypotheses
When you say HOW in your hypothesis, you are adding an extra variable.
For example, your hypothesis may be that if you shine a light through two small parallel slits that the light will travel in straight lines forming two bars of light on the wall behind it.
If the light travels how you expect it too (in straight lines), then no one usually notices, but when you instead get 4 bars of light on that far wall... suddenly, you realize that you are dealing with 2 questions instead of one.  What does the light do, and why does it do it?
This convolutes research because the goal of any experiment is to eliminate as many variables as possible so that you can measure one and just one thing.
Also, it is generally considered that no single experiment really proves any how or why on its own, but rather they build up with the results of many studies, but your Hypothesis is supposed to represent the question that your experiment will answer.
How and Why belong in your Conclusion
So once you see that there are 4 bars of light, you would try to answer how or why by comparing this data to similar other observations.  Since this pattern resembles wave patterns, you may then conclude that light probably travels in a wave pattern, but at this point you don't actually have enough evidence to prove it and you were never going to based on this single experiment.


Do hypotheses need a “how” explanation or are predictions enough to validate them?

Predictions and experiments are enough, you don't need mechanisms.
Large swaths of sports sciences are like this. Almost all training advice we have (e.g. for body building, running etc.) is based mostly on predictions ("if you train like this, then that will happen").  Of course there are scientists who do biopsies (i.e., cut out small amounts of muscle mass to see what happens if you train in a certain way), who measure blood levels of oxygen, lactate, and so on and forth, but this makes up only a very small amount of effort. The overwhelming majority of amateur and also professional athletes go directly from some kind of training regime to some intended result, just by trial and error (or prediction and verification), without really knowing how the mechanism works.
The same is generally true for science surrounding nutrition. Obviously we have some idea how carbs, fats and proteins are processed via very complex pathways in the body. But although we are investing a lot of effort here, much of it is not really that useful at all. Not necessarily because the scientists are doing something wrong, but because every concrete human body is slightly different, and there are an awful lot of mechanisms at work - thousands of them; and depending on circumstances one of those mechanisms can have some effect on one persons, and a different (or no) effect on others.
Medicine is similar. A lot of our western, "real" medicine these days can trace back the origin of drugs, for example, to medieval days when people just used random herbs to treat injuries or ailments. Nobody back then knew why they worked or how they worked, but they knew that if you gave a sick person a herbal tea made from that specific plant, they usually got better. If you gave sailors some fresh vegetables, they didn't get scurvy, etc.. Sure, these days medical companies are able to analyze the plants and maybe synthesize the relevant biochemicals, but I'm pretty sure that in many cases they still do not know the full, exact mechanism of why it works; they just know it works, and has no bad side effects, but they know this through trial and error, not necessarily via mechanisms.
Almost everything we know about the human psychology is like this. Yes yes, we know plenty of facts about the brain (e.g., the role of dopamine, serotonine etc. etc.) but in the grand scheme of things, it's really not much. Does that mean every reasoning about the brain (or about people) is invalid and unscientific? Of course not! It is is still perfectly possible, for example, for people doing marketing, to reason about how the psychology of consumers work, and go directly from cause "if we send 100000000 spam emails, a few people will fall for our scheme" or "if we make it so people go counter-clockwise in our shop, they will buy a little more than if we make them go clockwise". Nobody knows why and how that is, but it can be experimentally proven true (or at least likely), and useful, and can be regarded as scientific (you can measure it, you can check if it is the same for all populations and cultures, and so on and forth).

If we're focusing on scientific thinking:
Science is models of behaviour all the way down. We observe how something behaves, and we create a model for that behaviour.
For example, we observe objects moving towards one another, and we create a model that that is Newtonian gravity or general relativity to model that.
If we have a model of big things, which consists of small things, we can potentially create a model of those small things too, possibly explaining the behaviour of the big things. For example, we can model forces such as friction between objects on a high level, and we can also model that on an atomic level (atomic theory is itself a model).
This seems to be the best we can do to explain what we experience.
How do we pick a model?
To decide which model best explains the evidence, we can consider the explanatory power of each proposed explanation.
This includes factors such as how many observations are accounted for, how many "surprising" facts there are, having made correct predictions, how many additional claims the explanation makes that isn't accounted for by the evidence, how compatible and complementary it is with other scientific models we have, etc.
You can have a whole lot of correct predictions, and your explanation can still not be the most reasonable one because there is another explanation that is simpler, that has more correct predictions, etc.
For psychic powers bending a spoon...
Given that this is quite far-removed from how we understand reality to work, this explanation would come with a fairly significant disadvantage in comparison to other explanations. Never mind that many people make a living from tricking people in ways like this (and also specifically by bending spoons), by using a whole range of purely physical means, some of which can be really hard to figure out or spot, at least if you're not trained to do so, but also potentially even if you are. And every controlled test of such abilities have failed to validate the explanation (related: James Randi's Million Dollar Paranormal Challenge), which doesn't prove that it's impossible, but it certainly justifies being skeptical of such claims.
At first, it would certainly be more reasonable to conclude that some trickery is afoot, even if we can't figure out exactly what or how that was done.
But this disadvantage can certainly be overcome in order to accept the explanation of psychic powers. The way to do so would be with repeated tests in a controlled environment, to try to eliminate competing explanations (such as trickery). What exactly the scientific test would look like and when we accept the explanation - that's beyond the scope of this answer.
I'd also point out that "pure mind control process or hidden physical explanation" is a questionable dichotomy. It may be that there's some physical force generated by the brain, creating this (hypothetical) effect. As a physicalist, the idea of non-physical forces seems incoherent. And that's not really what one would testing here (I don't even know how you'd test that). You're just testing whether thinking leads to the spoon bending, by whatever mechanism.


The more of our experiments confirm a hypothesis about an observable
fact, the more science is urged to find an explanation of the
mechanism behind.
Science strives not only for confirmed hypotheses, but for the
explanation of confirmed hypotheses.
The question is not only “yes or no?”  but also “why?”
Example: As far as we know each day the sun rises and sets. Hence
scientists searched for the mechanism behind. Eventually Newton
eventually found  the laws of  celestial mechanics. Later his result was generalized by Einstein's General Relativity.

Of course one can now ask: Why do the laws of General Relativity
hold?
Science admits that currently this question has no scientific
answer. But the research for the "why?" will continue.




But if we assume tons and tons of successful predictions, can we finally believe or increase our credence in this pure mind control process, or should we still fall back into thinking there is a hidden physical explanation given the absence of a “how”?

Richard Carrier would be happy to concede that magic (or mind control, in your example) would eventually become an acceptable explanation:

Dembski’s goal was to identify that there are things that are not random like poker hands, yet are also complex. The basic obvious point is that certain things are so complex, that random chance is not a good hypothesis to explain how they arose or why they continue (like, if you kept drawing flushes, no matter how hard you tried to randomize the deck each time). Which is why we then start proposing other hypotheses (e.g. a card shark is rigging the deck); and in the sciences, we’ve developed tools for testing those hypotheses to see which is most likely the cause of the observed complexity (e.g. ruling out the card shark).
At some point, we would even have to concede magic is involved, were it so.
For instance, if we ruled out every hypothesis we can think of for the weird “every hand draws flush” phenomenon, yet someone present says they are controlling it with magic—and we can control for that, by having them “turn on and off” the magic for us; and having them show the effect in a wide variety of circumstances, particularly ones it is extremely unlikely they could rig or control any other way, e.g. like at several different tables at several different casinos, with no prep time—then magic would, alas, become the most probable explanation of the effect. Science would then start studying that magic, like it does any other power or force in the universe. And soon we’d have peer reviewed sorcerology journals, and the whole shebang. It’s the fact that this never happens that forms the empirical argument against the supernatural.

